# Trying to get property of non-object error but works when page is refreshed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I get the error in the title sometimes but when I refresh a few times, my application works again.

Laravel.log shows this:

> [2016-12-19 13:17:22] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with
>   message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in
>
> storage\framework\views\e81b4a67320194ba9a4782ec91b02d51:12

storage/framework/views/e81b4a67320194ba9a4782ec91b02d51.php line 12:

```
<span class="block m-t-xs">
    <strong class="font-bold"><?php echo e(Auth::user()->name); ?></strong> <!--line 12-->
</span>
```

Comment: That's a Cache file. Might want to check the corresponding view file to see what is causing the issue instead of the Cache file itself

Answer (score 4):

do `Auth::check()` or `Auth::user()` before trying to access fields in user object. Its because that you are trying to get a property of the user object, but the user object is null. like this

```
<span class="block m-t-xs">
    @if(Auth::check())
    <strong class="font-bold">
        {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    </strong>
    @endif
</span>
```

Comment: Yes, you should check if the user was auth through the Auth facade.

Comment: It turned out that it had to do with Auth::check() returning false but the root issue was to do with cookies. After clearing cookies and logging in again it worked without crashing

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `Auth::check()` returned false but app didn't log me out. After clearing cookies and logging in again this error stopped happening.

I suspect the issue was that I changed the user and auth quite a bit but didn't clear cookies

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the session has the authenticated user or not using `auth()->check()`:

```
<span class="block m-t-xs">
    <strong class="font-bold">
        <?php echo (auth()->check()) ? e(Auth::user()->name) : ''; ?>
    </strong>
</span>
```

> You can use ternary operator to check if the user is authenticated or not.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Why you 're trying to use `e()`? try to `dd(Auth::user())` then see the result or try

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

Comment: e() because this is the render of the template